# ApplicationBarIconButton is null

Tags: windows-phone-7

Why is my **ApplicationBarIconButton** null?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" x:Name="appBar">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="appbarSave"
          IconUri="/Icons/appbar.save.rest.png Text="Save" IsEnabled="False"
          Click="appbarSave_Click" />
    </shell:Application Bar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

The appBarSave object is null, and trying this:

```
Initialize Component();
appbarSave.IsEnabled = true;
```

Results in a NullReferenceException. The only place the object works is in the click event (if I enable it):

```
private void appbarSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationBarIconButton button = (ApplicationBarIconButton)sender;
    button.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

I would really like to be able to start the save button as disabled and enabled it later.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I remember running into this issue before: there's an explanation [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-are-the-applicationbar-objects-not-frameworkelements.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0). An easy workaround is just to instantiate it in code-behind rather than xaml (like [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/updating-applicationbariconbutton-dynamically.aspx)).

```
private ApplicationBarIconButton SaveEdit;
private void InitAppBar()
{
     ApplicationBar appBar = new ApplicationBar();

     SaveEdit = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("images/appbar.check.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
     SaveEdit.Click += new EventHandler(OnClick_Check);
     SaveEdit.Text = Strings.Save_button;
     appBar.Buttons.Add(SaveEdit);

     ApplicationBarIconButton CancelEdit = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("images/appbar.close.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
     CancelEdit.Click += new EventHandler(OnClick_Cancel);
     CancelEdit.Text = Strings.Cancel_button;
     appBar.Buttons.Add(CancelEdit);

     ApplicationBar = appBar;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

try this

```
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButton btn = ApplicationBar.Buttons[0] as Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButton;
btn.IsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Cool! This one Works!

Answer (score 1):

I use a bindable app bar control [from here](http://blog.humann.info/post/2010/08/27/How-to-have-binding-on-the-ApplicationBar.aspx) The download link is at the bottom of the article.

Makes life much easier and saves you from having to put code in the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

I made this mistake today, the x:Name is ignored.

The ApplicationBar is part of the page already, whether you create it in XAML or not. There is no need to create a new one. Just use the ApplicationBar property in the code behind file.

```
Initialize Component();
ApplicationBar.IsEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it so, example for change icon

```
ApplicationBarIconButton btn =  (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
btn.IconUri = new Uri("/images/play.png", UriKind.Relative);
```