# Dynamic appbar icon with text

Tags: dynamic, windows-phone, icons, windows-phone-8.1, appbar

I'm working on a WP8.1 app.

I have a circle in the appbar which is an button icon (transparent png).

Also I have a textbox on the screen of the app. When I enter a number in that text box can i show that number also in the middle of the circle in the appbar as well?

In other words can I have dynamic txt content in a WP8.1 app bar overlaid on top or bottom of a transparent Appbar button icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could have that number in that `appbar`. First you should get the value entered in the textbox using the `Tag` property. Then pass value to the `Text` property of the Appbar using the name you gave:

```
sampleAppBar.Text = //the value you get from the textbox
```

For more refer here:

[Programatically changing the appbar icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293376/programatically-changing-the-appbar-icon)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394044(v=vs.105).aspx

Hope it helps!